# Print a tongue twister!

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

The goal of this challenge is to print the following tongue twister:

```
She sells seashells by the seashore,
The shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.
So if she sells seashells on the seashore,
Then I'm sure she sells seashore shells.
```

This is more complicated than just calling your language's `print` equivalent. Since there are a lot of repeated words and phrases, you can greatly decrease the size of your code by using other tactics.

**Rules:**

- No querying another website which will respond with the full twister
- You must include all the punctuation and line breaks in the original text.
- You can end with a trailing newline

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!**

**Good luck!**

Comment: While there's a long history of natural-language text compression challenges coming down to a few built-in compression tools and tactics, I'm cautiously optimistic that this text's varied repetition and length will lead to some interesting solutions in at least some languages.

Comment: Probably just a pet-peeve of mine, but it always annoys me when a sentence ends in a comma, and the sentence on the next line is capitalized regardless. (Although that might also be related to not being able to use a sentence-capitalize builtin, haha. ;p)

Comment: It would be easier if the first line used `on` instead of `by`.

Comment: [What I made](https://github.com/Branzz/Code-Golf-Tongue-Twister) to find optimal solution(s)

Comment: 142 bytes is far from being the shortest answer. That would be "my pronoun is monicareinstate"s Bubblegum answer with 78 bytes. Shortest non-eso answer is my 126 bytes PHP as far as I can see.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen That is the standard convention for typesetting *verse* in English.  Each line starts with a capital, regardless of sentence structure.  It does not indicate a new sentence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>166</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>142</s></sup> 135 bytes

Saved a whopping <s>13</s> 18 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [user253751](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11600/user253751)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [branboyer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94107/branboyer)!!!
Saved 7 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!

Note: There's lots of unprintables in the following code so please avert your eyes if you're sensitive to such things! :D

```python
print("Sh by are,.\nSo if onnore.".translate("| seash|ells|ore,\nThe| sh|e s| I'm sure| the".split("|")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc2xCsMgFIVhtCZ9jYtLIwSXPkXmdMxi4RYFexWvHQK@u7Udz/cPJ5/VJ7r3nkuguujdT1JIeJ5XcVFSTRJcQSHX2R60Jwgv9e@JRqf5N1JBJa22tTji6CouugGjY98wRm6jrwc9PA4dBNxgu72BP2VI9agt5xjGddPGmN6/)

Based on [Netråm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87760/netr%c3%a5m)'s [C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206623/9481).

Comment: [152 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY2xCsMwDERxvkRoaQLGGPoVndOt7uCCigOuHCxlyNe7bobQ5fRO0nHrrqnwtbW1LqwjzolAKGfpGg28dtC@GWzge58m@FjpOFm4XT4gWyUXeC6wvIM/IoX/I3y@BT@Acei0RpYclcYHgpx1aLGbTj@gKKlUwuc0tfYF) with `translate` and without the `d` replacement. (There are some unprintables in the string)

Comment: [147 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYyxDsIwDESV9kcsL7RVlAG@grlstEOQjFIpOJUdhn59SBgQ0z3p3d1@5JD4UsouG@cB517JG3gckANBZxe@1TSgvReC5ixcTy/Qt5BbeE6wPav8jhL/j/jXq74D49Bl8azRZxruGNpbjApoUUOjBuQ1JCFcp/M4lvIB) by using more unprintables and modifying the first replacement.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add " I'm sure" to the dictionary?

Comment: @user253751 That wasn't saving any bytes in previous incarnations (in fact it was adding bytes) but is now saving 4 bytes - thanks! :-)

Comment: Your string still repeats `sea` thrice,  you could add that too

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Unfortunately, that doesn't save any bytes.

Comment: [142 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYyxDsIwDESVlg@xvNBWUQb4CuayUYYgGaVScKo4DP364IgOpzuf7nnbS0h8rXXLK5cB55OB196BBKMiEAM@q5HXxvZu4TnB@gbRXeKOe02pDYJx6Er2LNEXGh7YYIpR/ixabIcalHD8U84ufA/U2tv5A/LNhM/pMo61/gA)
[How I did it](https://github.com/Branzz/Code-Golf-Tongue-Twister)

Comment: I know this is an old challenge, but here is a [135 byte solution](https://tio.run/##Hc2xCsMgFIVhtCZ9jYtLIwSXPkXmdMxi4RYFexWvHQK@u7Udz/cPJ5/VJ7r3nkuguujdT1JIeJ5XcVFSTRJcQSHX2R60Jwgv9e@JRqf5N1JBJa22tTji6CouugGjY98wRm6jrwc9PA4dBNxgu72BP2VI9agt5xjGddPGmN6/) I found with a brute-forcer.

Comment: @dingledooper Never to late to do some golfing - thanks! :D

Answer (score 12):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>106</s> 103 bytes

```
S230 by41h012 are30,5.¶So if1230 on4n5123ore1h0.
5
 I'm1ure
4
 the3ore,¶The
3
1eash
2
he10
1
 s
0
ells
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcq9DYMwEIbh/pviujQI3flnCGqygCNddEhgSzYpshgDsJiB7pWet@q@5NQ7ZueZPv8gxuIoVfU8xPE85kLLVx4sOeR4V6l6TyMiaHpt8quKANpNHxnO420KD9HUDA6mwhBQA0PXtfV@AQ) Explanation: In Retina, a substitution only makes sense if it's long enough `l` for the number `n` of repetitions. The substitution saves `n(l-1)` bytes in the compressed text but costs `l+3` bytes in the replacement stages. This gives the minimum length required to be useful as follows:

- 2 repetitions: length > 5
- 3 repetitions: length > 3
- 4 repetitions: length > 3
- 5 repetitions: length > 2
- 6+ repetitions: length > 1

Edit: As @Arnauld pointed out, you can count repetitions from the substitution entries as well. This means that although there were only 5 repetitions of space+s in my previous encoded text, there are also 3 repetitions in the substitutions, thus allowing me to save 3 bytes overall. (@Arnauld himself had only spotted 2 of the 3 repetitions.)

Comment: Your first line isn't quite right. [Here](https://tio.run/##Ncy9CcMwGITh/qa4Lo0x6HeH1M4CCnxBBkcCfU6RxTyAF5OVIt3x8nBN9rWk3rF4jQyRzy93b6fzeHjN0aQmo05uPo@lcn2ZQWr5kyzFGcsBZxhQfx@wCLUJHHi/vamfsT2yEAEqSTMiZNu09ws) is a 111-byter I came up with, but you might be able to fix this at no cost.

Comment: @ovs Ugh, I wonder how far back I accidentally introduced that while golfing...

Comment: @ovs well, 106 bytes seems reasonable now. would be 100 bytes if the first line used "on" instead of "by" (see Wikipedia). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7DYQwEEXR/FXxsk0QGn@a2JhtwMGgQWJtycO2RgE05oX06tyux1bLGFgS3YQeWLpGmfJ8nUvjttJTzXePretDZmTw/frSf12REKKwVR6mj5iu82OKCLoWNwTYfQkEuu8@xh8 "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYqxCcMwEEX7P8V1aYxBOul2SO0soMCFMzgSSE6RxTyAF5Pl7vHeq7qvOfWOxUeh9z@wCXtKVaNMbj6PpdD64TuWHLIbVKqOaYYDPR9f/lWFhykLGNQQQLvpfU3n8TJFHFZTMwh021rvFw) with the patterns I used in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206652/58563) (except the last one which would result in +1 byte in Retina).

Comment: @Arnauld Nice, but you missed a trick, you still have two of space+s.

Comment: Well spotted! :)

Comment: @Arnauld I tried to rearrange the digits in your answer but I got it wrong the first time around so you had already updated your answer by the time I finished.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>142</s>  141 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

```javascript
_=>`246 / I'm5ure/he56/ the4ore,
The/5eash/ s/ells`.split`/`.reduce((s,p,i)=>s.split(i).join(p),`S0by35h652 are46,1.
So if50on3n1524ore5h6.`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc27DsIgGEDhvU/BJiQIvcHW7s51F2z/Cg0CgdbEp0eN8/mSs@mXznOycT/7sEBZh3IbRtX2EnF0OT3FkYAbEJKj3UAfEtDqaoAL0NlwlDk4lxXL0dldccUSLMcMGGcaqSXDmP8JW8K2YD2OhKqpvr87YaRokU7QS9qwagrIrqIOvvONaH@fL2CKlDn4HBwwFx54xYSUDw)

#### Compression steps

```
"ells" -> "6" (9 occurences, saved: 22 bytes)
She s6 seash6 by the seashore,
The sh6 she s6 are seash6, I'm sure.
So if she s6 seash6 on the seashore,
Then I'm sure she s6 seashore sh6.

" s" -> "5" (17 occurences, saved: 14 bytes)
She565eash6 by the5eashore,
The5h65he56 are5eash6, I'm5ure.
So if5he565eash6 on the5eashore,
Then I'm5ure5he565eashore5h6.

"5eash" -> "4" (6 occurences, saved: 18 bytes)
She5646 by the4ore,
The5h65he56 are46, I'm5ure.
So if5he5646 on the4ore,
Then I'm5ure5he564ore5h6.

" the4ore,\nThe" -> "3" (2 occurences, saved: 10 bytes)
She5646 by35h65he56 are46, I'm5ure.
So if5he5646 on3n I'm5ure5he564ore5h6.

"he56" -> "2" (4 occurences, saved: 7 bytes)
S246 by35h652 are46, I'm5ure.
So if5246 on3n I'm5ure524ore5h6.

" I'm5ure" -> "1" (2 occurences, saved: 5 bytes)
S246 by35h652 are46,1.
So if5246 on3n1524ore5h6.

"246 " -> "0" (2 occurences, saved: 1 byte)
S0by35h652 are46,1.
So if50on3n1524ore5h6.
```

Answer (score 9):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 115 bytes

Port of Neil's answer + accepting nph's suggestion.

```
/3/ I'm4ure//2/4eash//1/he40//0/ells//4/ s/S120 by the2ore,
The4h041 are20,3.
So if4120 on the2ore,
Then3412ore4h0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcoxDoMwDEbhnVN4Y0H8TuJLdKYXAMlVkAKR4jJw@uCOHd/TZ2W1rNY7Eug1HnI1BSJE/QMBWYUBhpZigIAMS4hM203frLE2nYa3o8wSaG0aeUrzsFTaP/Jz9fxzZ/Lr4X7u/QE)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nc0xDoMwDAXQnVNYwlYXxL9C1s70AkEyClJKpLgdmsuHUGCz/n/6tugtqNUKARlQEFQ0RiOA0ap2Aj3oc@TNpqwD4EDPx1u@WTEVU880//ruFZRYis8H5cGN3ZRoXeQUafuLzcn14t4jHmvdAQ "/// – Try It Online") by using ' s' (notice space) as a substitute.

Comment: I've bugfixed my answer; does that help you at all?

Comment: I was... maybe @nph was just confirming that it should help you?

Comment: @Neil I can't understand nph's behavior... it's bizzare.

Comment: @Neil I misunderstood. I thought you were talking to me because I just commented.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>91</s> 86 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
“SheÌç1€‹€€0,
The¬•s‚ÎÌç€™1,2.
So€¬‚ÎÌç1€‰€€0,
Then2‚ÎÌç0¬•s.“2Ý…½š¬•s#'í™ì“I'mˆ•“ª1ú:
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc4IzUwz2Hlxs@alrzqGEniGxaY6DDFZKReggosKj4UcOsw30gFSCplkWGOkZ6XMH5QA5IGioF0bwBWXOeEVzWAGKQHtAyo8NzHzUsO7T36EKImLL64bVAQw8DOXM81XNPtwEFgcxDqwwP77L6/x8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
“SheÌç1€‹€€0,
The¬•s‚ÎÌç€™1,2.
So€¬‚ÎÌç1€‰€€0,
Then2‚ÎÌç0¬•s.“  # Push dictionary string "She sells1 by the0,
                 #                         The shells she sells are1,2.
                 #                         So if she sells1 on the0,
                 #                         Then2 she sells0 shells."
2Ý               # Push list [0,1,2]
…½š¬•s           # Push dictionary string "shore shells"
      #          # Split it on spaces: ["shore","shells"]
       'í™ì     '# Prepend dictionary string "sea" in front of both:
                 #  ["seashore","seashells"]
“I'mˆ•“ª        '# Append dictionary string "I'm sure" to this list:
                 #  ["seashore","seashells","I'm sure"]
1ú               # Pad each string with a leading space:
                 #  [" seashore"," seashells"," I'm sure"]
:                # Replace all [0,1,2] with [" seashore"," seashells"," I'm sure"]
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the dictionary strings work.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>79</s> 78 bytes

<sup>removed trailing newline for -1 byte</sup>
The text in the tongue twister has many simple patterns. There are enough of them that even "normal" languages can save bytes. However, the *only* thing DEFLATE does is compressing simple patterns with little overhead...

```
00000000: 0bce 4855 284e cdc9 2906 9289 c519 6056  ..HU(N..).....`V
00000010: 52a5 4209 5018 2c90 5f94 aac3 1502 e441  R.B.P.,._......A
00000020: e58a e1ea 138b 5211 7a74 143c d573 158a  ......R.zt.<.s..
00000030: 4b8b 52f5 b882 f315 32d3 800a 310d cecf  K.R.....2...1...
00000040: c334 380f ae13 a105 a602 66ab 1e00       .48.......f...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc8xSwRBDAXg3l/xSgUJySTZmxEbrQRB5EBbnZmdsdFKr/HPr7O3iw/S5X0k5VTKZ/s4fS0L77kBl9pg0R0hWkOda0JIPCGFmFBdEib2CSB6eLl8IrqiNe@vF5sgw/CQHRY4wVkiQk0M78mQc1WIc0AzE@BI9/RM1/R2NuhuN8IwmseMJi1DNJZBiuCQDwYxrZj9sEJjBVv1SL8/dEvfRLuhw7BybnZHiTGgqzg0zIrInKHCM2qrHXgc/TVhjNC/YcOoqgaN3JGbKLKwI0/jg2nKBdKYsYUsbqdQH7Msfw)

After "writing" this answer, I finally decided to find a way to view the internal representation details of the string (to be specific, information on what characters are printed literally and what substrings are compressed as repetitions via LZ77). I modified `kunzip` (which already had some useful logging capabilities) to log only the information I want to see. This is the result:

```
output 83 S
output 104 h
output 101 e
output 32  
output 115 s
output 101 e
output 108 l
output 108 l
output 115 s
len: 3 dist: 6 ( se)
output 97 a
output 115 s
output 104 h
len: 5 dist: 10 (ells )
output 98 b
output 121 y
output 32  
output 116 t
len: 3 dist: 23 (he )
len: 5 dist: 17 (seash)
output 111 o
output 114 r
output 101 e
output 44 ,
output 10
output 84 T
len: 3 dist: 14 (he )
len: 7 dist: 28 (shells )
output 115 s
len: 9 dist: 48 (he sells )
output 97 a
output 114 r
output 101 e
len: 10 dist: 52 ( seashells)
output 44 ,
output 32  
output 73 I
output 39 '
output 109 m
output 32  
output 115 s
output 117 u
output 114 r
output 101 e
output 46 .
output 10
output 83 S
output 111 o
output 32  
output 105 i
output 102 f
len: 3 dist: 41 ( sh)
len: 18 dist: 89 (e sells seashells )
output 111 o
output 110 n
len: 18 dist: 89 ( the seashore,
The)
output 110 n
len: 9 dist: 58 ( I'm sure)
len: 10 dist: 51 ( she sells)
len: 8 dist: 34 ( seashor)
len: 8 dist: 118 (e shells)
output 46 .
```

I think might will be useful for "normal" language answers.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 171 bytes

```cs
string a=" she sells ",b="shells",c="seashore",d=a+"sea"+b;Write(@$"She{d[4..]} by the {c},
The {b}{a}are sea{b}, I'm sure.
So if{d} on the {c},
Then I'm sure{a}{c} {b}.")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxC8IwEEb3/orjEFQaM7lJwdW5goM4JOlpA20KuTpIyG@Pl0Vwe@@47zk@OPal8Bp9eIHpEHgkYJomBlS2Q1FhVE6QDI9LJFRDZ9qq2NrTLfqVducN9iOl4X7U@pHBfmCVTnJZNdcKNieTTaxpI6Lgsp2B35F00y/gn2nIsIS/Ufj9yFSONaJxX8oX)

The `@` allows for line breaks inside string literals.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing the `She{d[4..]}` to `S{d[2..]}`.

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes by changing `{b}{a}` to `{b+a}` and `{a}{c}` to `{a+c}`

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <sup><s>108</s> <s>105</s> <s>104</s> <s>96</s> <s>93</s></sup> 92 bytes

```
`S230 by41h012 ‡e30,d.
So if1230 4˜123Že1h0.`dd` I'm1¨e`4` e3Že,
T”`3`1Á`2`”10`1" s"0`e¥s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PyHYyNhAIanSxDDDwNBI4VB7qrGBTooeV3C@QmaaIUjuUK/JoRlA1qG@VKAavYSUlAQFT/Vcw0MrUhNMEhQOTUgFSelwhRyakmCcYHi4USjBKOHQFEODBEMlhWIlg4TUQ0uL//8HAA)

Port of [the retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206622/91267) to [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt).

### Explanation

```
S230 by41h012 ‡e30,d.
So if1230 4˜123Že1h0.
```

Decompress into the string literal:

```
S230 by41h012 are30,d.
So if1230 on4nd123ore1h0.
```

Then we do replacements with:

```
d
 d` I'm1¨e`     // "d" with " I'm1ure"
 4` e3Že,\nT”`  // "4" with " the3ore,\nThe"
 3`1Á`          // "3" with "1eash"
 2`”10`         // "2" with "he10"
 1" s"          // "1" with " s"
 0`e¥s          // "0" with "ells"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 83 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇσGª☺Uë\╠╤↑╡V╦⌐∞┐ü9B@♦1ÖFò╫◄«vâ¬♂ƒQn→↨¥p▬♂♥å↓hb½Z╫Éà½♣µ\╩N>.▄┌bæ¼@3▲¡w8╣▐ù☼ve/h{≈ï░
```

**[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80e547a60155895cccd118b556cba9ecbf813942400431994695d711ae7683aa0b9f516e1a179d70160b0386196862ab5ad79085ab05e65cca4e3e2edcda6291ac40331ead7738b9de970f76652f687bf78bb0&i=&a=1)**

#### How?

Unpacked:

```
`...`'!/|J
`...`      - compressed string "She sells..." with '!' where newlines should be
     '!    - a '!' character
       /   - split the compressed string at '!' characters
        |J - join with newline characters
```

Maybe making a manual compression using the words will be shorter?

Comment: Sometimes using an integer array is shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 154 bytes

```cs
Write(@"S{0}sea{1} by the {2},
The {1} s{0}are sea{1}, I'm sure.
So if s{0}sea{1} on the {2},
Then I'm sure s{0}{2} {1}.","he sells ","shells","seashore")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFXDQSm42qC2ODWx2rBWIalSoSQjVaHaqFaHKwTEAIoVA6UTi1IVIEp0FDzVcxWKS4tS9biC8xUy08DyUO35eSja8@BqwYqAwiAD9ZR0lDJAxuXkFCsA2cUZIBaIkZpYnJFflKqk@f8/AA)

Comment: [Here's some more 154 byte solutions](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFXDQSm42qC2ODWx2rBWIamy2qhWhyskI1UBxC0GyiQWpSpAZHWqjWv1uILzFTLTwDJQPfl5MD15QAUwmeKM/CKwIXpKOkoZICNycooVgOziDBALyFAoAQtDVIL4nuq5CsWlQLbmfy59LS6szgNrwudGuClYXYqiPQ@uFqwIKIzXvXCnanKR6TZc4YfqKlggEu0elKDD4TbygwxHaJERxeS4jW5JjktL/z8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>129</s> 130 bytes

```
-(i){|The shells|So if|Then I'm sure} {S|s}he sells {|are |}sea{|||shore }shells{& {on|by} the seashore,|{, I'm sure.|.->END}}
->i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxDsIwEAR7XnEVASnOE1JBQUOTfMBIh2wRbClHiuj23m5wIlHu7szG9CrFneJZMQYmCTxNgiFTfNYi0a15kywzG@kAscpUhBR@ZoIJewUgIf@i7b4eSXPCYzX6bILf5hba/v86uP56v5gdXB9L@QI)

- +1 byte: A period was missing from the end of a line

#### Explanation

```
// Thanks to all the new whitespace, this ungolfed code doesn't quite work as is
-(i)                              // A label
{|The shells|So if|Then I'm sure} // A sequence - the first time we get here we print nothing,
                                  // the second time we print "The shells",
                                  // the third time we print "So if", etc
{S|s}                             // Sequences keep outputting their last value once it's been reached
he sells                          // Plain text just gets printed
{|are |}
sea{|||shore }shells
{& {on|by} the seashore,|{, I'm sure.|.->END}}
                                  // {& marks a repeating sequence.
                                  // Instead of getting stuck on its last value, this it starts over.
                                  // On the fourth pass we hit ->END and terminate the program
->i                               // On the other passes, we get here and go back to the start
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>133</s> 126 bytes

```
<?=strtr("S2 s101 by t203,\nT2414e s1 are01,5.\nSo if4e s101 on t203,\nT2n54e s10341.",[" seash",ells,he,ore," sh"," I'm sure"]);
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75a045e313ee72788372b1a68da5156d0afc8d9a). Use PHP < 7.2 to avoid warnings

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, 158 bytes

Because if bash counts then why not...

```
$1="seash"
$5="ells"
$4="he s$5 "
$6=" I'm sure"
$2="$1$5"
$3="$1`ore"
"S$4$2 by the $3,`nThe $5 s$4`are $2,$6.`nSo if s$4$2 on the $3,`nThen$6 s$4$3 $5"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNCsIwEIX3nmIYBtwUofnb5QCu2wOkQiRCTSSjiBTPHifduXvve3zvUd6xcorr2hqNHjkunPBA1qMwlmQ8pghMFqQ4j3A@3oFfNUpVHmkkK0n3FEqnOJEhBZcPPEUkPYQ894ckF0yb@S5VsBrInUKeCtyugrtR8p@Rye2D3lVs7Qc)

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xym42qC2ODWx2rBWIalSoSQjVaHaqFaHKwTEAIoVA6UTi1IVIEp0FDzVcxWKS4tS9biC8xUy08DyUO35eSja8@BqwYqAwiAD9ZR005QyQObl5BQrKOkogd1RDGKkJhZn5BelKv3/DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [144 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xym42qAWyCpWSKqsNqxVAAsXgyiFYjArsQjESoSI6yh4qucqFJcWpepxBecrZKYpFMO05@cBtefB5cES@SAarFFPSTdNCW4m2DwlHSWFkgyo4UCVOlwhGalK//8DAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>134</s> <s>133</s> 132 bytes

-1 byte thanks @[Titus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55735/titus)

see similar by [Nail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206622/80745) and [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206652/80745)

```powershell
$d='S0by36h461 are54,2.
So if60on3n2615ore6h4.'
"154 #he64# I'm6ure# the5ore,
The#ells#6eash# s"-split'#'|%{$d=$d-replace$i++,$_}
$d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NasMwEITveoolUtEhtokTW4dCINee3Xtx7G1lcCRHqxBC22d31yY/pb1IsDvzzc7gzxjIYt@Po2q3ulrtLxtjC5NDHbAsknUmKg/du1l5t3Frk5c@IAsyLRZ5WYC0aAoJL/pgTgElRIuTIhGvFiVjSRqsyUqgRUpD30Ut9dfTJ2epNg049HWDqlsuE/X2LVQ7ai0EU5DiM6gYTsjZcKhjYyH6ic6f@@BxPHcUMbAnbfC406LiHU2J/NZzJYL9ZbbMg9tVcN3RXc9NH55k6gLEZa7NfwkfYO/@g93d@dfiwy01E3o3/gA)

Comment: Lose one more byte by putting " s" last, so you can use it in " seash". Beat my php!

Comment: Thanks! You [made php great again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206668/80745). :)

Comment: Your code inspired me. Excellent shell scripting! I almost wish someone could "bash" me. :D

Comment: Down to [130 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY9Ra8IwFIXf8ysuGgloLVbbFAYDX0ceu/cR27ulUJsuN0Vk7rd3aXE65ksC99zvnHs6e0JHBptmGHj1LIrN4byTJpUJ6DxLo23MCgv1u9zYdtduZZLZPMixYLMkS0EZlKmCF3GUfa7AGwx6xF4NqmBJSqImo4CUw9llAUW3BHVZfIUkXq0ddo0ukderVcTfvhmvBiEYm4NH8k/AvesxRMNR@9KAt6N9@NqPMPanmjy6wKxL/NwLVgSNxszw6qkQweE8IdPAOpzugqtGt33t8M5EYxeg3uG1@J/Fu7FtH43bG/kfse43NWZiP/wA "PowerShell – Try It Online") by changing the `split` syntax and factorizing `re`

Answer (score 4):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 110 bytes

```
iS230 by41h012 are30,5.
So if1230 on4n5123ore1h0.Í5/ I'm1ure
Í4/ the3ore,\rThe
Í3/1eash
Í2/he10
Í1/ s
Í0/ells
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzPYyNhAIanSxDDDwNBIIbEo1dhAx1SPKzhfITPNECSXn2eSZwpk5RelAtXoSR/uNdVX8FTPNSwtSuU63Guir1CSkQqS1YkpCskACRnrG6YmFmcAWUb6GamGBkCGob5CMZAy0E/NySn@/x8A)

Port of [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)'s [retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206622/91267) to [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>179</s> 176 bytes

```
print"She sells seashells by the seashore,\nThe shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.\nSo if she sells seashells on the seashore,\nThen I'm sure she sells seashore shells."
```

Trivial algorithm, but nobody’s done it yet. I’m working on a better answer in a different language, but I don’t know if it should be posted in another answer or in this one. Shortening advice accepted, but I’m perfectly fine with just hard-coding it for now.

Comment: If you do come up with another answer, you should almost always post it separately. You should generally only include multiple answers in one post if they are extremely similar. Good luck!

Comment: You have a space you can remove after print, and in Python 2 you can remove the `()` around the string

Answer (score 3):

## [PicoLisp](https://picolisp.com), <s><sup>160 157 146 142</sup></s> 138 bytes

```
(prin(text"S@1 @2 by the @3,
The @5 s@1 are @2,@4.
So if s@1 @2 on the @3,
Then@4 s@1 @3 @5.""he sells"'seashells'seashore" I'm sure"'shells]
```

Using the template:

```perl
S1 by the 2,
The 5 s1 are 2,4.
So if s1 on the 3,
Then4 s1 3 5.
```

Where 1 is `"he sells"`, 2 is `"seashells"`, 3 is `"seashore"`, and 4 is `" I'm sure"`

[Ideone It!](https://ideone.com/hyfZvI)

<kbd>{ <sub><sup><sub>14 imaginary interweb points for guessing which syntax highlighting I'm using without peeking</sub></sup></sub> }</kbd>

#### Common Lisp, 160 bytes

```
(format t"S~a~a by the ~a,~%The shells s~3:*~Aare ~a, I'm sure.~%So if s~3:*~A~a on the ~a,~%Then I'm sure s~3:*~a~*~a shells.""he sells ""seashells""seashore")
```

https://ideone.com/n7zVUm

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>169</s> 160 bytes

```java
v->"".format("S%sells by%s shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.\nSo if s%1$sells on%2$sn I'm sure s%1$sore shells.","he sells seash"," the seashore,\nThe")
```

Port of [*@IgbyLargeman*'s C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206661/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!
-9 bytes thanks to *@branboyer*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVCxbsMgFNzzFScUq7bkILVr1O4dmsVRlqYDITgmxRDxsKWoyre7YKwscNy7d7rjKkaxuZ5/J2kEEb6Etn8rQNugfCukwi49gSZ4bS@Q5cHpM8ZqG9nHKh4URNASO1i8Yxo3H4zx1vlehJI1BSljCKd7QaBuxvFCZoVPSGS@xudLDxq84kfbOOgWVLyus9LZ4m1N9inJI5fAvMxZzZ62s2UkELrFPwrro913ilXTNmW@DScTMy/Rx9Soj8XLXPL7B6JaWt8pqJ67IfBbHIXSclnawZhq@YDH9A8)

(Simply returning as is would be [174 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDNjsIwDITvPMWIy7YS5AUQ3DnApYjLsgcTAgRSB8VpJbTi2UsK5UeIixWPM7a@OVBNw8Pm2GhHIpiR5f8eYDmasCVtMG9boIjB8g46W3q7QZ2PknrppSKRotWYgzFGUw8n/WJvIMY5SZVkf3utz4g3OQk@mMGKF217H8rTQMG8TANMf0pIFYxaceFht28/X6s9f1nNT@@nx4fHXdVvRi3BqVq7RNCB1C1fmWLI7si/f6C8y@As0ZTKV1Gd0ihmrHTGlXN5F8eluQI).)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->           // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  "".format(  //  Return the following formatted string:
     "S%sells by%s
      shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.\n
     So if s%1$sells on%2$s
     n I'm sure s%1$sore shells.",
    "he sells seash",
              //   Where the first `%s` and all `%1$s` are replaced with "he sells seash"
    " the seashore,\nThe")
              //   and the second `%s` and all `%2$s` are replaced with " the seashore,\n
                                                                         The"
```

Comment: [160 bytes](https://tio.run/##PVCxbsMgFNzzFScUq7bkILVr1O4dmsVRlqYDITgmxRDxsKWoyre7YKwscNy7d7rjKkaxuZ5/J2kEEb6Etn8rQNugfCukwi49gSZ4bS@Q5cHpM8ZqG9nHKh4URNASO1i8Yxo3H4zx1vlehJI1BSljCKd7QaBuxvFCZoVPSGS@xudLDxq84kfbOOgWVLyus9LZ4m1N9inJI5fAvMxZzZ62s2UkELrFPwrro913ilXTNmW@DScTMy/Rx9Soj8XLXPL7B6JaWt8pqJ67IfBbHIXSclnawZhq@YDH9A8) (This can be ported to the C# code as well of course)
I'm attempting to create code that'll find the best solution; that's the best I got right now.

Comment: [My github link](https://github.com/Branzz/Code-Golf-Tongue-Twister) to the finished project for optimizing this problem (could be used with other similar problems).

Comment: @branboyer Ah nice, I will keep this comment in mind if a similar KC challenge is posted. A brute-forcer to get the shortest substrings is a nice approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 287 bytes

Trying a different way of compressing it, in a different language. Feedback is appreciated!

```javascript
function s(){a="kdg by the dj,/nThe g care dg, I'm sure./nSo if cdg on the dj,/nThen I'm sure cdj g.".replace(/c|k/g,function(match){return(match=="c")?"she sells ":"She sells ";});c=a.replace(/d|g/g,function(match){return(match=="d")?"sea":"shells";});return (c.replace(/j/g,"shore"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBNbsIwEAXgfU8x8qa2FJItwrK6Zk0vYCaDSTA22A4SAs4ehp823XXnJ7/5RprenmzG1B3K7DQfx80QsHQxQJbqYo3YtQ7WZyhbgravmvDNDwdoE2dXwfJzD3lIVDdhFaHbAHKfp//2w2@Lf3twtagTHbxFkg1ed42rfpbKvS24VZdEZUjvZIxAob5EZjGT9xnEQqymoG9Ko7ET2V7d/2T7JMmyxTBDT@dVAomT1rPFlZhIKKVv4xHM4zT6A2PI0VPto5NHpcc7)

Comment: Compressing attempts made it longer, annoyingly. I don't think it can be shorter, but I would appreciate help.

Comment: You could use an arrow function in the replacer?

Comment: Hey, you asked for some feedback (a bit late, I know), so I worked through how I'd golf this answer: https://gist.github.com/dom111/717ecd767f252b883059b9ecaf63ca67 I'm sure there is still a lot of room for improvement, but I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 77 bytes

```
ΓJx'p¨½ΞĿ∫Ẏj5pż¦Sβyεḟ?ṡ,ḣŀḢ¦ṠεΞĿ∫äeŻaŀ`◄,İ'm ṡ→.¶ȮSÏf£2₅Φεḟ?ṡ,ḣnİ'm ṡ→⁸ρΘŀḢ¦.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9xkrwr1gkMrDu09N@/I/kcdqx/u6ssyLTi659Cy4HObKs9tfbhjvv3DnQt1Hu5YfLTh4Y5Fh5Y93Lng3Fao6sNLUo/uTjzakPBoeovOkQ3quQpAtY/aJukd2nZiXfDh/rRDi40eNbWeW4ZiUB6SykeNO843npsBNVvv/38A)

Better than Bubblegum!

Husk's string compression is pretty good for this task, a straightforward compressed string would be 82 bytes long. Here, we apply just a single substitution to make it shorter.
The compressed string  we use here is

```
he sells seashpSpells by the seashore,
The shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.
So if spells on the seashore,
Then I'm sure spore shells.
```

The structure of the code is:

```
ΓJx'p¨...
     ¨...  The compressed string
  x'p      split on occurrences of the character 'p'
ΓJ         and joined by interleaving the first substring between the rest
```

What this does in practice is replacing the character 'p' with "he sells seash" everywhere in the rest of the string.
This substitution was the one that generated the shortest compressed string among the ones I've tried; multiple substitutions are possible but they didn't seem worth the longer payload. The letter 'p' was chosen because it generates words like "spell" and "spore" in the text that can be compressed very well by Husk.

Comment: (asking here since the chatroom is locked) What does `ƒ` do?

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>1313</s> 1234 bytes

```
iiissiic{ii}icdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}ddsddc{ii}iiic{{d}i}ic{dd}dsdddddc{d}ddcdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{{ii}}dc{ddd}ddddcdsiiic{ii}cdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{{iii}ii}ic{ii}dddc{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{d}iii}dc{d}ddc{iiii}ic{ddd}ddddc{{i}ddd}c{{d}ii}iiic{dd}s{ddd}iciicdddc{d}dddc{{ii}}ic{{ii}ii}cdsiic{iii}ddc{{d}ii}ic{{iii}iii}dcdddc{{d}iii}c{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}ds{d}cdc{{d}ii}iic{dd}dsdddddc{d}ddcdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{{ii}}dc{ddd}ddddcdsiiic{ii}cdddc{i}dc{{d}ii}iic{iiii}ic{ddd}ddddc{{i}ddd}c{{d}ii}iiic{dd}s{ddd}iciicdddc{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{d}iii}ic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVNBDsMgDHvRHjXFm@YzR5S3M0ICrbZqK2qnHdrQ4sSOCbhdcWd6XEohmRIpmVQKAMkZyvaVAU31hbZWtF1alB5zzTNsfbCJjyRDt3@ypwiQIosmzQSFHNtAlMIOuW/0QdnqYrCrE/ekxHDkC4PMOnLU4OxrZfSEpYkpFzaJMESrw3u9rsyRGlA/mxUbY37WttJjszLGzFVEidESX8w53brTZrNWqc0sJvxvLn0khozDB/Z5zH9r/Vb/c9euo0t5Ag)

Deadfish, the ungolfing language.

Comment: It can be outgolfed best if human mind and generators are combined, nicely done!

Comment: @Wasif Not actually human mind, my generator implements that, but not actually anything clever :p

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>1216</s> 1196 bytes

```
iiissiici{ii}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cdddcddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}c{d{i{i}}}ciii{ii}ci{i{d}}c{iiii{iii}}cdd{d}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cddd{i}ciiicddd{d}cd{{ii}}c{d{{i}}}cdsiiic{ii}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cd{d}cdddcddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}ciii{dd{i}}cd{d}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}ci{ii{iii}}cddd{ii}cddd{d}ci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cdddcddd{i}ccddd{i}cd{iii{d}}cdd{d}ci{iiii}c{d{{i}}}c{ddd{i}}cd{dd{ii}}ciii{dd{i}}ciicdddcddd{d}ci{{ii}}c{ii{ii}}cdsiicdd{iii}ci{ii{d}}ciii{ddd{i}}cdddc{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cd{d}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cdddcddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}cd{dd{i}}cdcii{ii{d}}c{iiii{iii}}cdd{d}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cddd{i}ciiicddd{d}cd{{ii}}c{d{{i}}}cdsiiic{ii}cdddcd{i}cii{ii{d}}ci{iiii}c{d{{i}}}c{ddd{i}}cd{dd{ii}}ciii{dd{i}}ciicdddcddd{d}ci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cd{d}cdddci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddd{i}ccddd{i}c{{d{{i}}}}ciii{dd{i}}cdddd{d}cddddcdd{ii}cd{d}cddd{i}ciiicddd{d}ci{iii{d}}ciii{dd{i}}cd{d}cdddcddd{i}ccddd{i}ci{iii{d}}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVNJEsIwDHsRj2KsMuicoydvD7GzToF2CodcateLLCsJtjseDM9bSiRDIIVKRgHgHhUxilsooyeQY2bzvzSrCrX812KIxQy5Bg4Qskd3Hcua8teJGCOn5eAN6Yzo22ybl0ullag6YmMgCJY9EeJ8j0/Vv4qq095ozKzn8vL7KegAEyAnNRRjCRSlplFFxsGmSlkOrkhZGLBuMah2rnIo8LJ7iN4v7NTXXMFa3/X774zWqb1b@9LLGsUpvQA)

As long as I didn't mess anything up, this should be the shortest possible without `()` and printing in loops.

Answer (score 2):

## [FEU](https://github.com/TryItOnline/feu), <s>112</s> 111 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Neil

```
a/S256 by43h632 are56,1.\nSo if3256 on4n1325ore3h6.
m/1/ I'm3ure/2/he36/3/ s/4/ the5ore,\nThe/5/ seash/6/ells/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxDsMgDAX3foW3LlGewOB/6JyOWajk1JUSkKAZ@vWUbKe72/TsPWHxUej1C2zCnlLVKJOb17wU@mx8xZJDdoNK1THNtwMO9LgffFaFhykLGNQQQF/T65vW/DRFHFZTMwh03xvevf8B)

Port of JavaScript answer.

Comment: The `0/256 /` replacement only makes sense in the JS answer because the `0` is implicit as the match; here it actually costs you a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>175</s> 158 bytes

thanks @branboyer for the edit!

```python
print"S{0}ells by{1} shells she sells are seashells, I'm sure.\nSo if s{0}ells on{1}n I'm sure s{0}ore shells.".format("he sells seash"," the seashore,\nThe")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoMwDER/xfJSkKKo7V90hpElSEFBAhvF6YAQ3x6CW5jubN87L2sKTO@clzhSwmZ77n6aBPp1e@0gQYciIOpcPJ377Q18HjPIN3rbUcMwDiAXz1R4ugN64FOVtGgHjrNLFd7VWosGIYX/j5I3HbXBY53zAQ)

Comment: [158 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoMwDER/xfJSkKKo7V90hpElSEFBAhvF6YAQ3x6CW5jubN87L2sKTO@clzhSwmZ77n6aBPp1e@0gQYciIOpcPJ377Q18HjPIN3rbUcMwDiAXz1R4ugN64FOVtGgHjrNLFd7VWosGIYX/j5I3HbXBY53zAQ)

Comment: [156 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoMwDER/xfJSkKKo7V90hpElSEFBAhvF6YAQ3x6CW5jubN87L2sKTO@clzhSwmZ77n6aBPp1e@0gQYciIOpcPJ377Q18HjPIN3rbUcMwDiAXz1R4ugN64FOVtGgHjrNLFd7VWosGIYX/j5I3HbXBY53zAQ) Sorry to change so quick

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 155 bytes

```scala
printf("S%2$s by%1$s shells%3$sare seashells, I'm sure.\nSo if s%2$s on%1$sn I'm sure%3$sshells."," the seashore,\nThe","he sells seashells"," she sells ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsIwEER/ZQkNKoSC@gUePXhqj72kdUsidROyERTx22PSSj0NvJk3POhJJ9ffcIhw0ZYAnxHpynDyHt7JB0tx3IpGHiqG/iX3OdjgNLE8VqwDAqNegILz5g78CFh31DiwI/CsOSoarXUxF6UWSkA0vxMXUHXUGsx0Znnxvy9TXrHYpU/6Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 128 bytes

```sh
<<Z
S${4=${2=he s${1=ells}}${3= seash}$1 }by${5= the$3ore,
The} sh$1 s$2 are$3$1,${6= I'm sure}.
So if s$4on$5n$6 s$2$3ore sh$1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw7DsJADAX7PYULSzRRpM2vig9AHSq6IBkZKWSlNRRg@ezLknbevPmqlDLP17CgDYTWkTAoWiTeNnVH6wmUVxXHCH77oI0EL2HsU@YmXIQdVOqm2MGaK8fYoE0E59MT9J3Z27AkeNyrMaQdxx2nv3wEjmtbyg8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1269 bytes

```
iiissiic{ii}icdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}ddsddc{ii}iiic{ddddddddd}ic{dd}dsdddddc{d}ddcdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{{ii}}dc{ddd}ddddcdsiiic{ii}cdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{{iii}ii}ic{ii}dddc{d}dddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{ddddddd}dc{d}ddc{iiii}ic{ddd}ddddc{iiiiiii}c{dddddddd}iiic{dd}s{ddd}iciicdddc{d}dddc{{ii}}ic{{ii}ii}cdsiic{iii}ddc{dddddddd}ic{{iii}iii}dcdddc{ddddddd}c{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}ds{d}cdc{dddddddd}iic{dd}dsdddddc{d}ddcdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{{ii}}dc{ddd}ddddcdsiiic{ii}cdddc{i}dc{dddddddd}iic{iiii}ic{ddd}ddddc{iiiiiii}c{dddddddd}iiic{dd}s{ddd}iciicdddc{d}dddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{{iiii}iii}dc{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}ddddcddddc{ii}ddc{d}dc{i}dddciiic{d}dddc{ddddddd}ic{dd}s{ddd}ic{d}dcdddc{i}dddcc{i}dddc{ddddddd}ic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVNbDsMgDDvRDjXhTfM3nxFnZzwSoBpSi8a0ShVpSGLHSfG440n/usVI0nvSCRnoADhBfdJnMoMXswPKNfPp7JSUmFPTi2m8JuXo4nNXigBes0g2Ro1TvoXWwxXSHyQUuFZvHEKFtyRPFeYMwq0K87XQUu1A7QqtjUUhZkhWwgRW5EGa4snOPhubVIOkrdMgL@tZJNWtUyoDbel9HujsV3HbuqYqqaODGH9cVKU1UNkxwLP1//EcJkIs/pA9PMY3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 138 bytes

```php
O+S=q+=sS=v" shells"4F" se"=tSvT0"sea"F2"S"+" by"+=p" the seashore,
The"+v+s+" are"+t+=u" I'm sure.
So if"+q+S" onn"3Fp+GuF9+s+Gp 4 9+v"."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVhtc9rGFv4Mv2KtjJEWiUSSuTMtIBgnMR5PHTs1zu0Hm6ayEEYzQlBJOG1j37@ee86@SLuA06YtHxC7e16fPW8i6txH0ZcXSRalm1k8KMpZsnq5GDbVnTS507ai8vd1vEWUJ9m9tlUmS04zi@dJFpM0Jekqu2df1eb1xYd3xKuXk@sr4tfL/x5fkW69HF@8Id/Vy6sPxKuJx@cThfbiw7lC@uHi3fHkB6ugxIKv1v@8/9Dq7HgCSvlRtAjzNq2IVRqwU7IPh9365OLkJzzK4Ah9eYRfg4F@juLZOfx4tNKUwkojeH15ec4o4GsEXvXAFUX31Sk/BNbKuIcw3cSU3mRT2mwys@EG4nAZXBknl2Pry6U9CX61g2ISPBikWMRpWhjdMfyMjaCcPFy7RhGHxtg3JoZtkLvfDTtYG6RcxEARFotVHjvN60Vs2A92AQRhDj9LO9gY5MxckmKTxy@bkxVJ5ob9qz0xyCrLjKPx2j7djL8HjtM16ZLv7QfjpfGFgkFGvwnXvw7zIrYo@dxsJFlJkn6zAbvMFYe055ssgh10hkSwLpdrp1hnN/40@Ow67lO/CWwk4PTwdIH40yJJYwtcB0KLI@AQ47a8zW7ntzn5/HQztWjvhUGZ0kYyJ5YAigQBMV@YlHARcvcAdm8z2LZtvgNKGnFaxOrGk1BMrKSYJfdJKdlBDVroOZWR/Nkmnkts0hYm2jYlHWK6JshCkxJK8rjc5BlPh0fCr5cMBqRLKy@TIl19inMrArFSH3l8JNKGiK0i5thHkwp3kz2uJIHnALpBtb1lBGYdGAGRSoAkm23WFl4GERh1CKyoYOP6bk2zVm6YHG2gAlMr7eTVKwK1AX6DCeuwKHm4lWFeArEAtC0RwpuIUElDWoWl4c@sgm@P8htSvMYocqdgSyR9LTbrNUJJ5f3LHRVYNVIAUEUgypBBt84g4qAyYYwJUzkM1yYZsRrVExtj3MAq1cPqhOEso4QVNu6bhWmApoZpuoqsrut4FD3Cbd0JLvRKAf69WZnAJEs2D9lE8u2z/vjk9Ztffjw4f3upOKFJ8HclHGgiTs8mz/Ee7fJyc0/NyvKzZyzv6rw6yRPWlHyTIWx9VgShaKwKS9YUFoUQX2USEXZ6t5nf@N2pMIKD32I5V2kv1tDHyrkFpODVYZrODJnMwyFko4NCtgVAZFYCeDfh@jW6AfGOdCfRc4yPETHKfBMbEBfVPoYJ7M9DyFc8MLJNmho1BOgnui76AILx8fVqlcLBnQ7As67WXn3Nn/a3O6RaebdtJd5Zucr@VRshEstVmlqqqQ5xHai6f8PkbMdkbFbvjt9fONiyeJzB8uzGc113yjobLOWqSP6IP5YEH/1mHaGKt4gArBz88tn3UeDJzodFB5sfPti3zx9HQDA@Oz9pkznUq36jimyhD0thFK6dNM5Yo1SwskRX4ZhBzj0HxjYjNgLsI/NVDjWTtVzobwOGRR8Ke4KHVTGIluutG2AgJdO6LiBMyRTVFJ@SMlpYbTbTEH2oAYyI@ETYK8xjs0dQCycIEFAciqAw0hZzSogXs5gWsrTPWl5NwYa9Msf2wea9myn9XIcZzBms3HLFV6BYl52H2cyiLfe3OXxqwvdACEI5RPdxmcLgZrXYVbbwgrBLzZKM9pO5ZbHrxOYbLXI0xYEwpZTfcuD295oKD7RL6jvh@lh3YrVA4NGX5iJGom7WVr6u3eH01cmb@gQ5VYQrml@ABoMBwi9Yr9ZxZimKHSM3WLcGq4Il710QjoHvdr9j@6K/W3womIPpM3QKpiKIWAdHJiCH9s1WqANUy@iyYJPYARs7MGGBkgq4QQ7TxaBGCe2A@OrYUMNYe/IjeBL/BiMTJvuOnwfapbPZ/AAL2Q7h@U50gJZUx0Uhf2v2xEy2J46rwif6j3GxWd7BPIIdiMoWhC8e9RC3Uw0l64S9i1mHBTLqubDLDHDCMKLqhUJKjZpUHmB3icNMiH2ugYmOpd6AbOgchcsaBUwMuEIBGr9PDTrSauHpTaeDpFM@ad6y0bYhzTp82S7AHgtWlMhUyxXzN2Uhb7@KCT59cYPsyiBWJqFcYkXG0FKuhw@0Df22@UshUsOMTWQs@fzOcQRlycAvgFHhNmZ5IL306f5QjcJSPsQc6Nk1TFT@RlkU5kOHPUtRI4RfnZ3oVKIdp2XdXs7Urm9nDwrb3XkPDu0dHPi97kNhuce1NqMJVCGMAVqQxSpkYN7CexMS9TsdJk8AxTrm9kVzREst@199FZhX@4E5/CrT4X6mnxmamkN8mGd7vuplX8DOUQ9Ix6tQZrQAvQd51vEgxzyV2P9G6gGUR402CJCU6e3JHVdCzoD2h67A2qdsWmkHDP/mdkKwQ6VLDZj/W7UU80hLtUBPtBFR42mgIousPf4/CjBzghHRRg@26RAlwVCGyzllFfd5aUHagwAKmGLy8J@bPPwXTB5Kkw/22BwIm4XJo@dN5lr3mIzHI6IR@BWFL2vvwT4760XlngxaVUBlXqvOHPRlX1kZqZwiCiv@x7/CL8JXEVPx982eSq1NSNu0QZ2w@vE3j8ByLKpnYKRraHNwlUWMBiVOA41byTDkQArbrti4yT@Be/wvDHVG0bwjatsTbGf6wIekCv/I7x0psJzyaTNQmrOt1q7d6ToTM6tT5cKRNgtNONBbQvvb1dLfVy2PaNVC/Iq7yzb/pJeiYfjEq4iqubHqpGpb9cFD1Gp72F9Zb@Hxzw/Zg1HYIhNA@yyeh5u0BM/kcJJkcJjM2L8PYVTGOTSSyMRxBXcoeeb9B4Wx@VT8l/XE3kCXYZJZFP/SYC8h@Pe65TLF@rD/9OX/)

Fiiiiiiiine, I'll explain it

##### Attempt at explaining it

Sorry, the indentation is a little inconsistent...

```php
OUTPUT
 +
  # substitute " s" with "S" for initial capitalization
  SUBSTITUTE(
   = _she_sells_seashells
    + = _she_sells
     # inject " se" into "shells"
     # to get "she sells"
     SUBSTITUTE(
       = _shells " shells"
       4
       0
       " se"
      )
    # inject "sea" to get " seashells"
    = _seashells
       SUBSTITUTE(
        _shells
        1
        0
        "sea"
       )
    )
    0
    2
    "S"
   )
  + " by"
  + = _the_seashore_the " the seashore,\nThe"
  + _shells
  + _she_sells
  + " are"
  + _seashells
  + = _im_sure_so_if "  I'm sure.\nSo if"
  + _she_sells_seashells
  # shorter to inject than concatenate
  # to get " on the seashore,\nThen"
  + SUBSTITUTE(
     " onn"
     3
     0
     _the_seashore_the
    )
  # Extract "I'm sure"
  + GET(
     _im_sure_so_if
     0
     9
    )
  + _she_sells
  # " seashore"
  + GET(
     _the_seashore_the
     4
     9
    )
  + _shells
  : "."
```

Comment: explanation por favor

Comment: Even the creator of Knight himself can't decipher my magical code? ¡Ay caramba!

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 156 bytes

```
i=" I'm sure"
h=" she"
k=lls
l=" seashe"$k
s=" seashore"
e=" se"$k
printf "She$e$l by the$s,
The$h$k$h$e are$l,$i.
So if$h$e$l on the$s,
Then$i$h$e$s$h$k."
```

An expert can probably save some more here.

Comment: Consider using [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCsMwDEV3n0IYQZeQG@QAnZMLOKAgYdcOVjr09K4UKHQQ@u/pa0/KY8gS4fl4gb47xcBGyhbyUoqG4kjJDeagP2pepZvcn13qdUBcmZCwwP6By6JOYbPFmG0IUrfbhDKHtYEc7qzb6l@3otxa/WmOY3wB "Bash – Try It Online") - it counts your bytes and also creates MarkDown for you.

Comment: [151 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY0xDoQwDAT7vMKyLF2D@EEeQM19gBCjRILkFHMFrw8mQLmzs1o3SajVWZTA6ypoZouwBwZhbXJhNF7J8NlA/leKFlvb5F@JaV8AR4rXgBy4g@bOfFXRIIqnwnfVke/NmCEujd96To@eyL@43eq8x1pP)

Answer (score 1):

## [zlib](https://zlib.net/), 84 bytes

Hex dump:

```
00000000: 78 9c 0b ce 48 55 28 4e cd c9 29 06 92 89 c5 19  x...HU(N..).....
00000010: 60 56 52 a5 42 09 58 18 28 90 5f 94 aa c3 15 02  `VR.B.X.(._.....
00000020: e2 41 e4 8a e1 ea 13 8b 52 11 7a 74 14 3c d5 73  .A......R.zt.<.s
00000030: 15 8a 4b 8b 52 f5 b8 82 f3 15 32 d3 90 14 22 0c  ..K.R.....2...".
00000040: ce cf c3 34 38 0f ae 13 5d 4b 7e 11 cc 56 3d 00  ...48...]K~..V=.
00000050: 3c 70 3a e6                                      <p:.
```

Raw hex:

```
789c0bce4855284ecdc929069289c519605652a54209581828905f94aac31502e241e48ae1ea138b52117a74143cd573158a4b8b52f5b882f31532d39014220ccecfc334380fae135d4b7e11cc563d003c703ae6
```

Or generate this file yourself:

```
openssl zlib < seashells.txt > seashells.zlib
```

You can <s>decompress this file</s> execute this program with:

```
openssl zlib -d < seashells.zlib
```

or, presumably, any of the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix).

Comment: Assuming I remember what header is used by gzip and what header is used by zlib, If you remove the first two bytes, this becomes a Bubblegum answer. (note that I already posted a shorter one)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript: 195 bytes ...?

```js
console.log(`She ${a='sells'} sea${c='shells'} by the sea${e='shore'},
The ${c} she ${a} are sea${c}, ${d="I'm sure"}.
So if she ${a} sea${c} on the sea${e},
Then ${d} she ${a} sea${e} ${c}.`)
```

Simplest JavaScript answer possible. Simply defines commonly used words.
Annoyingly, compression made it longer

Comment: Just using 'sea' is shorter than '${b}'

Comment: Kinda true, let me fix that

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 133 bytes

```perl
say"S5s0 10 by t513,
T5sh02are 10, 4.
So if210 on t513,
Then 4213 sh0."=~s/\d/(ells,seash," she sells ",ore,"I'm sure","he ")[$&]/ger
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco5DsIwEEDRPqcYjRCLNHhJ4pIDUFCFDiiMGEikEEeeUKTh6BhT0P7/Ro69S0n8jI0TA9bAdYbJ2YqKo5PWlD5yrgS1KpoA3b3MJAx/0vIAdWkryFTh7i36fNNr7nshYS8tYT4M8iuAFCIT7ldPkFdkJMwLN6fF8qIfHFP6hHHqwiBpe3DKGmW@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 150 bytes

```
I{ECA}H{\ }G{\r\e}F{H\I\'\mC\uG}E{\h\e}D{H\tEB\oG\,\
\TE}C{H\s}B{C\e\a\s\h}A{\e\l\l\s}\SIBAH\b\yDC\hACIH\aGBA\,F\.\
\S\oH\i\fCIBAH\o\nD\nFCIB\oGC\hA\.
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#SXtFQ0F9SHtcIH1He1xyXGV9RntIXElcJ1xtQ1x1R31Fe1xoXGV9RHtIXHRFQlxvR1wsXApcVEV9Q3tIXHN9QntDXGVcYVxzXGh9QXtcZVxsXGxcc31cU0lCQUhcYlx5RENcaEFDSUhcYUdCQVwsRlwuXApcU1xvSFxpXGZDSUJBSFxvXG5EXG5GQ0lCXG9HQ1xoQVwu)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3.0.0beta.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 77 bytes

```
"dyrΦ<ᶲrᵞjvG#IZᶳ²∵nᶨ₂ᶜ8G6OẠ′zḃṁɠ₉EFḟih←Xᵞᶻ1d²i)`⁰!⌐=x‴¶ᶢ↓•ƓΦ…ᶢɾʀ5ḋỌḄcGᵒıɾᶪ×‴”
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.github.io/#WyIiLCIiLCIiLCJcImR5cs6mPOG2snLhtZ5qdkcjSVrhtrPCsuKItW7htqjigoLhtpw4RzZP4bqg4oCyeuG4g+G5gcmg4oKJRUbhuJ9paOKGkFjhtZ7htrsxZMKyaSlg4oGwIeKMkD144oC0wrbhtqLihpPigKLGk86m4oCm4baiyb7KgDXhuIvhu4zhuIRjR+G1ksSxyb7htqrDl+KAtOKAnSIsIiJd)

> This is more complicated than just calling your language's `print` equivalent.

Is it now.

Simply a single compressed string. No string formatting, no substitutions. Just one string.